# Shiny validate for read.csv

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use shiny validate function to capture reading errors and show customized error message when reading uploaded csv files instead of letting shiny forward the default read.csv error message.
Here is the simple code

```
validate(need(try(sd <- read.csv(file = sdFile[1], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)), "Error reading the file"))
```

when there is no format issue in the csv file, the code works normally. But when there is an issue with the csv file, the code still returns the default error message (in red font), eg., Error: undefined columns selected, but not the customized message. Any issue here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is actually printing it out, if I do this:

```
library(shiny)
validate(need(try(sd <- read.csv(file = "mtcars1.csv", 
                                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)), 
                                 Error reading the file !!!"))
```

yielding:

> ```
> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, "rt") :
>   cannot open file 'mtcars1.csv': No such file or directory
> Error: Error reading the file !!!
> ```

I get this - note your message is the in the last line.

You can suppress the warnings with `supressWarnings` like this:

```
library(shiny)
suppressWarnings(
+ validate(need(try(sd <- read.csv(file = "mtcars1.csv", 
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)),
                          "Error reading the file !!!!")))
```

yielding:

> ```
> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
> Error: Error reading the file !!!!
> ```

Or you can supress everything but your message with this (uses `tryCatch` instead of `try`):

```
library(shiny)
suppressWarnings(
validate(need(tryCatch(sd <- read.csv(file = "mtcars1.csv", 
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE),      error=function (e){}), 
                             "Error reading the file !!!!")))
```

yielding

> ```
>  Error: Error reading the file !!!
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I think my error is not related to reading the csv file but something else. Yes, it should work fine.